# Setting coolbits on KDE Neon 5.27 goes wrong

Tags: linux, xorg, fan, kde-plasma-5

I'm trying to set my KDE Neon 5.27's coolbits to 8 in order to gain manual fan control access using Green With Envy. Otherwise my laptop's fans are constantly firing loud even at stupidly low temperatures.

I didn't find any xorg.conf file in /etc/X11 and I'm too much of a noob to make one myself, so I ran `sudo nvidia-xconfig --cool-bits=8` as I saw recommended in a few forums, which did create the file with the right setting, to my knowledge.

So I rebooted, and was greeted with a black screen with `_`.
I could press enter and login from there, but no GUI. I tried `startx`, which did output a few lines, until it just went back to a black screen with `_` as above, and I logged in again.

Rebooting didn't do any better, so I assumed my xorg.conf file went wrong and `rm`d it. Then rebooting gave me back my GUI, but still no access to my fan speeds, using Green With Envy.